# Custom UID, GID creation in android

Tags: android, linux

I am interested to write an application which will enable the phone owner to create a UID and GID with empty folders structure.

Say for example “ls -l data/user/0” on Nexus emulator 4.4.2 shows

```
drwxr-x--x u0_a47   u0_a47            2014-07-23 07:34                com.android.gesture.builder 
drwxr-x--x u0_a28   u0_a28            2014-07-16 02:28                 com.android.htmlviewer  
drwxr-x--x system   system            2014-07-16 02:28                com.android.inputdevices  
drwxr-x--x u0_a29   u0_a29            2014-07-16 02:30                 com.android.inputmethod.latin
```

Here by installation of package  com.android.htmlviewer, UID u0_a28 and GID u0_a28 is created.  Any new application installation will generate new sets of UID and GID. I want my new application should be able to call appropriate APIs to create such UID and GID.

I am interested to know if there is any API available to create distinct system identity/distinct Linux user ID. What is the general process followed by the android installer to create such id during any package installation?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Some more question

UserManager class is supposed to be the class based on [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java). It has functions like createUser, supportsMultipleUsers getUserCount,getUsers, removeUser  wipeUser , getMaxSupportedUsers.

One function createUser says “Requires {@link android.Manifest.permission#MANAGE_USERS} permission” ; How we can use the function from [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/os/UserManager.java) which are not exposed, in some sample application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no API to let you do that that would be available for apps in normal Android runtime environment.